# How to set the background for every second button in Table Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-tablelayout

I made a grid of buttons dynamically in the program, I used to do this TableLayout , this is my code:

```
    private void createLayoutDynamically() {
        won = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.won);

        for ( int qq = 1; qq < a; qq++) {
            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
            tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(

                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    2
                    ));

            won.setPadding(25,25,25,25);
            won.addView(tableRow);

        for ( int q = 1; q < b; q++) {

            myButton = new Button(this);

            tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    2
                    ));
}
}
}
```

The result of this code is something like this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uli6s.jpg

I want to achieve that the background of these buttons change every second like here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVKXe.jpg
Can u help me ?

Comment: u can use a counter variable, and in each for count plus 1 it, and then divide it to 2 and if the result is zero.so change color and if not, do nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When filling table rows add to your loop:

```
for ( int q = 1; q < b; q++) {
    myButton = new Button(this);
    int drawable = R.drawable.first_button;
    if (q%2 == 0) {
        drawable = R.drawable.second_button;
    } 
    myButton.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(drawable)); //you can put Resources to variable and put it outside the loop
    tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
        TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        2));
}
```

Comment: Ok, it works :), Can u explan this part of code  q%2 == 0 ? How this works ? I ve added to if , else with second drawable.

Comment: % is remainder operator. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html

Comment: If q = 1, 3, 5, 2k+1 (q%2 == 1) - button has first background. Else if q = 2, 4, 2k (q%2 == 0)- button has second background. This if-else can be written as (if q%2 == 0) { button.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.first_bg);} else {button.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.second_bg;} that are very similar. So we put outside call to button.setBackground() and call to Resources.getDrawable. we need an int R.drawable descriptor. (int d = null; if () {d = /**/} else {d = /**/}) and then call setBackground and getDrawable only once.